# i recovered my formatted partitions, how is that possible?

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery

I have just recovered all of my deleted C partition which I formatted it accidently by writing "clear" command on (diskpart) windows command line two month ago. How is that even possible? How that works? I delete it, it frees up storage but again can be recovered, so it wasn't removed at all? Can someone explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to a comment from [Ramhound](https://superuser.com/users/83283/ramhound):

> Data can be recovered until it's overwritten with other data. When you delete data, it's just marked to be removed/replaced by the file system, the data can be recovered until it's replaced with different data.

From a comment by [Tmanok](https://superuser.com/users/762205/tmanok):

> As said by Ramhound the data was never deleted, just "unallocated" from your active drive. Meaning physically the data was sitting there, but marked as non-existent on the index of the drive.

From some comments by [Mokubai](https://superuser.com/users/19943/mokubai):

> If all you did was clear the partition without creating a new one then the initial structures of the disk will remain, with the exception of some predictable information that will point at the partition you erased. The actual partition data would still be there and would be detectable so that the "here is a partition" can be recreated.
>
> If you wrote data to the entire disk then your data would be gone. This is why the best thing you can do after accidentally deleting something is to stop using the drive entirely and recover it on a different machine or live cd